# How to build a tiled image gallery where the bottom is a straight line?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

We can use a plugin like Masonary to grab a set of images and create a tiled image gallery. But most of the time the bottom of the gallery will not be a straight line. How can we make sure the images are fit perfectly so that the bottom is straight like shown in this image :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Justified Gallery](http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/). It has good animations and you can control it. It is straight.